# what is the complexity of my Python program? Complexity newbie

Tags: python-2.7, time-complexity, code-complexity

```
def multiplyItself():
 i=[2,3,1,4]
 j=[]
 length=len(i) # 0 1 2 3
 print 'input string',i
 for l in range(length):
  if l==0:
    j.append(mul(i[l+1::]))
  if l>0:
    print i[l+1::]
    print i[0:l]
    j.append(mul(i[l+1::])*mul(i[0:l]))
 print j


def mul(l):
 sum=1
 for i in l:
   sum=sum*i
 return sum

def main():
 print 'test multply'
 multiplyItself()


main()
```

---

Above python code works, but I am not sure of the programs complexity. Can anyone give me more insight?

Actual question is below:
 input [2,3,1,4] 
output [12,8,24,6]

Multiply all fields except it's own position.

Restrictions: 
1. no use of division 
2. complexity in O(n)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take it one step at a time:

1. `mul(l)` performs an operation on every element of `l`. Its complexity is therefore `O(len(l))`.
2. Since `j.append(mul(i[l+1::])*mul(i[0:l]))` operates on `O(len(i))` elements, its complexity is `O(len(i))`.
3. Since the `j.append()` is repeated `len(i)` times, the overall complexity is `O(len(i)*len(i))` or `O(n**2)` (where `n` is `len(i)`).

In conclusion, you need a different algorithm.

Hint (mouseover to reveal):

> Would it help if you were to multiply **all** the elements together?

Comment: Explanation is good. Although I didn't understand your hint. Can you please elobarate?